# Finding nodes with Xpath wildcard on name

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a document with lots of nodes like this:

```
<FOO_A />
<SOMETHING />
<FOO_B />
<WHATEVER />
<FOO_C />
```

How can I use xpath to find all the nodes with names that match FOO_*?
Thanks for all advice.

Comment: If you have generated these documents, you found a way how *not* to use XML. Elements that represent equal types of things ought not to have different names. Imagine how easy it would be if all Foos were actually called `<FOO>`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The nodes are different, just all with the same prefix within a certain application.

Comment: That's my point. Don't use prefixes, suffixes or numeric counters in the element name. That's what attributes (or child elements) are for. `<FOO type="A">` is *way* better and more useful than `<FOO_A>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short and sweet:

```
//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'FOO_')]
```